# Costa Rican empanada-like food?

Tags: pastry

So I went to Costa Rica and tried a a savoury pastry that is similar to empanadas but it is not empanadas. The pastry had a yellowy-orange colour, the shape of it was rectangular and it was stuffed with some sort of flavourful meat. I really want to know what the name of this food is.

Comment: Most likely something like a [Jamaican meat pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_patty)? There are quite a few varieties of those from Costa Rica to Trinidad, can you remember more about the filling and seasoning? Was the crust really flaky? The color you describe brings it to mind.

Comment: maybe just one of million local variation of empanadas in Central and South america ?

Comment: @Max having been to Costa Rica I think you're right. We had things called empanadas that matched the OP's description. I remember having them in the centre of the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a **Jamaican Patty.** From  [Explore Costa Rica.com](http://www.explorecostarica.com/newsmanager/publish/Costa_Rica_Food_Recipes_Jamaican_Patties.shtml) :

> A Jamaican patty or pattie is a pastry that contains various fillings and spices baked inside a flaky shell. Technically, it is a beef filled turnover. As its name suggests, it is commonly found in Jamaica, and is also eaten in other areas of Costa Rica, especially on the Caribbean coast. It is traditionally filled with ground beef, however, fillings now include chicken, vegetables, shrimp, lobster, soy and cheese.

[image]

[image]

[image]

They are quite tasty!